# Webmaster tools shows zero page indexed

Tags: google-search-console

I have a website with over 60 articles (dynamic pages), a couple of profile pages, about sections, terms of use, contacts, pretty much everything. I've added my site to webmaster tools and it seems that it is being crawled but not indexed. I don't have a site map but I have other pages which are designed in the same way, yet they seem to be indexed fine. What could be the problem?

[image]

On a second thought it seems that very few pages are crawled.

***Could it be that all my pages are on sub domains?***

Comment: As well as not enough information this question has been asked in various forms, please use the search and you will find many questions that are similar with lots of great answers why Google may not be indexing your site.

Comment: What? I've been searching google and stackoverflow for quite some time. I've read all the other topics ands still I have no idea why google is not indexing my pages. Apparently there is something to do with subdomains but I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: If you provide the URL in question, I'll take a look. The question was not only closed because it is duplicate as it stands but also because its impossible to answer, it could be 101 reasons why.. If you share the URL as I said I'll take a quick look, im on the chat channel by the way should you want not to share it on here.